# Simplify binary and and xor in C

Tags: c, binary-operators

Is there a way so simplify the following expression in `C`?

```
result = (constant & value) ^ value;
```

The use case being:

```
#define ALL_SENSORS = (BIT(0) + BIT(1) + BIT(2) + BIT(19))  # = 524295

static int get_invalid_sensors(int sensor_mask) {
    return (ALL_SENSORS & sensor_mask) ^ sensor_mask;
}
```

Is it possible so simplify the binary operations into one, so I do not need to invoke `sensor_mask` two times?

Comment: Compilers are good at  doing *constant folding*, where all compile-time constant expressions can be calculated by the compiler itself and only the result will be in the generated code. Compilers can also generate code that reuse results previously calculated, especially if it can deduce it won't change in-between (which constants never do). So please build with optimizations enabled, and look at the generated code. I'm sure it will be as optimal it can get.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: sensor_mask is a variable so some of what you're saying isn't quite true! All I can think of is 'ALL_SENSORS & (~sensor_mask)'

Comment: As a general rule when it comes to optimization: It's almost never worth to do low-level micro-optimizations like this on your part. The compiler will almost always be better at it. Not to mention that hand-written optimizations tend to be obscure and hard to read, understand and maintain. If you have performance problems, profile an optimized build, and concentrate on the top *two* (or maybe three) bottlenecks.

Comment: Is `ALL_SENSORS` a constant? For example, `BIT(x)` is just `(1 << (x))` and not something weird like a function call or a macro containing `sensor_mask`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil `ALL_SESNORS` is a constant, yes. `BIT` is a macro, which does the exact bit shift that you described.

Comment: Please add the new information to the question, not here in the comments.

Comment: @RichardNeumann — SESNORS --> SENSORS if you are quick

Comment: If there is then the compiler will do it

Comment: Using `int` for bitwise arithmetic is almost certainly wrong, so you might want to replace that with `uint32_t` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `(~ALL_SENSORS & sensor_mask)`?

Comment: This isn't quite the same! If ALL_SENSORS was, say, 0x0f and sensor_mask was 0x08 then this would return 0 and not 0x07!

Comment: @Skizz `(0x0f & 0x08) ^ 0x08` is 0.

Comment: oops, brain fart moment! So wouldn't it always be 0?

Comment: @Skizz Or in truth table terms, `((0 & 0) ^ 0) == 0`, `((0 & 1) ^ 1) == 1`, `((1 & 0) ^ 0) == 0`, `((1 & 1) ^ 1) == 0`. Compare with `(~0 & 0) == 0`, `(~0 & 1) == 1`, `(~1 & 0) == 0`, `(~1 & 1) == 0`. They are the same.

Comment: @Skizz No it would not always be 0. E.g. if `sensor_mask` is 54321, then the result would be 54320.

Comment: I think the ~ is in the wrong place, this would set bits that aren't in ALL_SENSORS (see comment above about naming!)

Comment: @Skizz  This gives all bits which are set in sensor_mask but not in ALL_SENSORS. So does the one in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Well if you put this (or atleast similar) code into [here](https://godbolt.org/z/48qjPn). Then you can see the optimized code for example for RISC-V is

```
get_invalid_sensors: # @get_invalid_sensors
  not a0, a0
  and a0, a0, a1
  ret
```

From this you can realize that `(~ALL_SENSORS & sensor_mask)` is sufficient as already said. But you can also realize that the compiler will most likely be able to optimize your code anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The goal of the expression `(ALL_SENSORS & sensor_mask) ^ sensor_mask` is to mask all bits in `sensor_mask` that are not in `ALL_SENSORS`. You can do this by `~ALL_SENSORS & sensor_mask`, too.